# Is there a point to building the Reset Center other than Resetti coming out when you reset?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have recently built the Reset Center, but never have reset my game. Are there any other advantages to building it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reset Center provides the following things (the first being mentioned in your question).

1. Now, when you reset without saving, Mr. Resetti himself will come to your home and yell at you!
2. After rainy days, there's a chance of the manhole being open. You can climb down it to visit Mr. Resetti, and after five (?) visits, he'll give you his picture for you to mount on your dining room table!

It's not much, but at least you get a picture hehe.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/66487974)